# Ajax in a class instantiated via shortcode

Tags: php, plugin-development, ajax

I've written a booking plugin for WP. The main plugin file only contains some initialization (DB tables, instantiating of the class with all the actual code).

Here's a part of my code that I consider relevant to the problem.

Plugin file:

```
function stiqboAdminInit() {
    add_shortcode("stiqbo-calendar", "stiqboCalendarInit");
}

function stiqboCalendarInit($atts) {
    $stiqboCalendar = new calendar($atts["coachid"], "coach");
}

add_action("init", "stiqboAdminInit");
```

Calendar class:

```
class calendar {    
    public function __construct($coachID, $calledBy) {

        //Data is being retrieved from DB
        //Variables are being initialized
        //Scripts/Styles are being enqueued

        add_action("wp_ajax_changeTab", [$this,"changeTab"]);
        add_action("wp_ajax_changeSettings", [$this,"changeSettings"]);

        //A lot more add_action commands like these

        $this->renderContainer();
    }

    //Lots of methods
}
```

The instance of the calendar class I'm calling via shortcode here works fine apart from the Ajax requests. I always get HTTP 400 errors (which I know are coded in WP_Ajax when the Ajax action referenced by JS isn't found).

I've already tried quite a few things, but nothing worked so far.

Where and how do I have to define these Ajax actions to be able to use them? Do I need to change the way the shortcode interacts with the class? If possible, please don't suggest solutions that involve functions.php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you register the AJAX endpoints only when the shortcode is called. to use them, you need to register them e.g. on the hook `wp_loaded`.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that I have to register the hooks before there even is an instance to reference?